How can I represent elegant FMT settings for a BAR LABEL in pandas plot?
Here's a function that generates a barh graph and displays a bar label
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_theme(style='white')

def plot_barh(s, unit='', title='', f=0):
    ax1 = s.plot(kind='barh', figsize=(6, 3),
                 width=.8, title=title)

    ax1.bar_label(ax1.containers[0], padding=10, color='black',
                  fontsize=10, fmt='{:.' + str(f) + 'f} ' + unit)
    ax1.set_xticks([])
    sns.despine(bottom=True, left=True)

Plot sample data s, in a graph like this
s = pd.Series({'John': 7, 'Amy': 4, 'Elizabeth': 4, 'James': 4, 'Roy': 2})
plot_barh(s)


Decimals and units can also be represented
plot_barh(s, unit='point',f=1)


fmt='{:.' + str(f) + 'f} ' + unit code in plot_barh func make this, but I'm struggling to find a more elegant way to express the argument of fmt.
I've tried f-string or the format function, but I get an error.

Am I using something wrong?
Or are f-string or format functions not supported?
and if not, why not?

What exactly is your question? Being "more elegant" is a subjective, there always will be use cases that aren't as easily supported (scientific notation, tex, ....). String formatting has a long history both in Python and in matplotlib. As such, a rich variety of possibilities exist, but not every function allows all of them.  About the "why": matplotlib is maintained by unpaid volunteers, many of them dedicating large chunks of free time to create extensions and improvements. Did you notice you can use the library without paying anything?
